# Matching products to one or more customer requirements [MS SQL]

Tags: sql-server, select, matching, temp-tables

On our website, a customer can save one or more 'wish list' records that describe what they want to buy based on type, price, etc. We then use these records to send emails to them each day about new products that match their requirements.

I need to query a customer's Wishlist records in one go and output all the records added today that match using a stored procedure. Customers can then easily view any matching products within their Account page, and we can also use the code for the emails.

**EXAMPLE PRODUCTS TABLE**

ID: 1243

- ProductType: Shirt
- Brand: Nike
- Price: 39
- Colour: Red

ID: 2342

- ProductType: Shirt
- Brand: Adidas
- Price: 49
- Colour: Blue

ID: 6456

- ProductType: Trousers
- Brand: Nike
- Price: 29
- Colour: Black

ID: 3423

- ProductType: Trousers
- Brand: Fila
- Price: 49
- Colour: Red

ID: 7656

- ProductType: Shirt
- Brand: Fila
- Price: 19
- Colour: Black

**EXAMPLE WISH LIST RECORDS FOR CUSTOMER # 2**

AccountID: 2

- ProductType: Shirt
- Brand: Nike
- MaxPrice: 50
- Colour: Blue

AccountID: 2

- ProductType: Trousers
- Brand: Nike
- MaxPrice: 30
- Colour: Any

So I need to pass in the AccountID to a stored procedure and output any products that match any of the Wishlist records.

This is as far as I've got so far, getting the two wishlist records into a temp table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MATCH_CUSTOMER_REQS
   @AccountID int
AS
BEGIN
   /* select all wishlists */
   INSERT INTO #TempTable (ProductType,Brand,MaxPrice,Colour)
   SELECT
   ProductType,
   Brand,
   MaxPrice,
   Colour
   FROM Accounts_Wishlists
   WHERE fk_AccountID=@AccountID       
END
```

I've no idea how to loop through and put together a list of all the products that match.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest learning the basics of SQL from resources online and books rather than asking for answers here. This seems like pretty basic SQL, hence I'm going to refrain from answering. You'll learn more if you learn for yourself. You'll more than likely get an answer with SQL that will answer your question, but it's unlikely that the users that answer will provide good explanation for you to learn something from.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT  b.ProductType, b.Brand, b.Price, b.Colour
  FROM  Accounts_Wishlists AS a
  JOIN  PRODUCTS AS B 
    ON b.ProductType = a.ProductType
   AND b.Brand = a.Brand
   AND b.Price <= a.MaxPrice 
   AND (a.Colour = b.Colour OR a.Colour is null)
 WHERE a.AccountID = @AccountID
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried joins but I don't think I can ignore nulls in the Wishlist table. "Any" is actually denoted with a null value in the wishlist table, and I need to search products that match TROUSERS, NIKE, < 30 and Any colour. Using your example, a Wishlist with a null to denote ANY COLOUR will return no results even if there are products that match TROUSERS, NIKE and < 30. I need some way to say if the Wishlist field is NULL, include any non null value in the Colour field. I've googled extensively to try to figure this out but not found anything. Help much appreciated!

Comment: You can simply change it to: AND (a.Colour = b.Colour or a.Colour is null), code is updated.